# Ubuntu 14.04 will NOT load except for empty desktop

Tags: unity, grub2, 14.04, toshiba-satellite

When I start up my computer, this is exactly what happens:

1. GRUB loads, and I select Ubuntu.
2. Ubuntu is loading, and before Step 3 a tty1 screen shows up, then goes away
3. Ubuntu login screen shows up, and I type in my password.
   PROBLEMATIC STEP: 4. Ubuntu shows only a bare desktop.

I use my Ubuntu a lot, and a few days ago I saw that the GRUB version showed beta in it, and also the commands use to boot it up are different when I saw the commands used to boot up Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Can you please show us a screenshot or a picture because in your case you might not be able to take a screenshot. Thank you!

Comment: No, because I have to restart the computer and there is no way of saving screenshots that I know of.

Comment: I mean take a pic using your mobile or camera or any other gadgets.

Comment: My cell is broken, but I can explain in words what I see.

Comment: What do you want to know exactly?

Comment: Like what can you see? Only the wallpaper or also the panel or also the launcher, etc.

Comment: Can you move this to chat, cause I only have 1 rep.

Comment: Sorry Dhinak can't because you have only 1 rep

Comment: Well, only a desktop with default pic of 14.04. No icons, files, Unity, menu bar, etc. This happens on all the accounts

Comment: Does Ctrl-Alt-T work? Doesit launch the terminal?

Comment: No. It seems that the system did not load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first perform a memory diagnostics check in the grub menu list it is after

advanced options for ubuntu

live media and to do this have a look at following link

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

if the live media doesn't work try using safe mode

Comment: Memory is OK, but I don't want to lose my files when using live media to reinstall.

Comment: If you boot to the live media and choose "Try Ubuntu" you should be able to copy your files to a USB

Comment: @DhinakG I also wanted to convey same as Charles Green said and there will be no data loss for Boot repair

Comment: I have stuff that can not be copied, such as apps, which can only run on specfic hardware and I do not have enough space to copy.

Comment: @DhinakG you don't need to copy stuff after repairs system is booted into the last time where it worked properly and even the memory diagnostic will not do it , and memory diagnostic will just fetch orphaned files and recover them

Comment: I will try but I have a really bad feeling I nedd to reinstall.

Comment: take a deep breath and goo

Comment: I updated my video card drivers and reinstalled. I had a very slow computer. Any help on this?

Comment: yes but did this answer helped?? and if yes then make it the answer and you can use light versions of ubuntu desktops other than unity like lubuntu and xubuntu try installing any one of these it will help